# Restful Java - Grant access to resources

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, rest, restful-authentication

I developing a resful webservice that will have differentes resources (the application database stores urename and password).

On the other and I have a client that can access to those resources. To access to some of these resources the client must be registered (existing in the database). Im using GAE as application server and Jersey to create the Restful WS, so my question is what is the best way to access this resources?

I thought in sending  the username and password in the WS request (as POST) and then check if the couple exists in the db and answering at the request.

Do you think this kind of authentication is secure (I dont think I can use https on GAE)?

Thanks in advance fo the responces

Danilo

Comment: As a rule of thumb, sending a password that can be used more than once over an unencrypted connection is not considered secure.

Comment: GAE supports HTTPS - http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2008/10/announcing-https-support-for-appspotcom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using OAuth 1.0 or 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use some form of transport layer security such as SSL to secure your service.

Also, REST tries to make use of HTTP features, so you could put a Authorization header in the HTTP request.

Edit: a simple example

**Transport Layer Security**
Go to one of the many companies that sell SSL certificates, for example Verisign. Buy a certificate. Install it on your web server. You web server will have documentation on how to install it.

**Using HTTP authorisation**
Get the client of your web service to use BASIC authorization (they are passed in plaintext so you've got to be using SSL for this to be effective). This involves putting the BASE64 encoded username and password in the [Authorisation header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Write a security `Filter` and configure your web app to pass all requests to your RESTful service through the filter. Your security filter should extract the username and password from the request Authorisation header and check them. If the credentials are invalid you reject the request with a 403 status code. If the credentials are OK, just propogate up the filter chain.

```
public MySecurityFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {

    //Get the Authorizatiuon header
    String auth = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getHeader("Authorization");

    //Extract the username and password

    if (checkCredentialsOnMyDatabase(credentials[0], credentials[1])) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      //Reject the request with status code 403
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that if you are using one of the popular frameworks like Jersey then it has a lot of security functions built in that may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you please give me an example?

Thanks for your time